# Android L Developer Preview packages missing?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to use the Android L Developer Preview SDK, specifically the Bluetooth Low Energy classes.  I set `compileSdkVersion 'android-L'`, `minSdkVersion 'L'`, and `targetSdkVersion 'L'`.  I can see the L platform SDK under "External Libraries", but when I go to see what is inside the android.jar, the android.bluetooth.le package is missing.  Thus, I cannot use any of the Bluetooth LE classes such as BluetoothLeScanner and ScanCallback.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess this is a bug in Android Studio (there are some other APIs for which this has been reported too)...

If you write something like:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner scanner = adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
```

then this is indeed reported as an error in Android Studio. However, it **does** build ok when using `gradlew build`.

In short, you *can* use it, but it's really awkward. I hope this will be fixed soon.

Comment: It must've been an Android Studio bug, I updated to 0.8.2 and the problem went away!

Answer (score 0):

It must've been an Android Studio bug, I updated to 0.8.2 and the problem went away!