# Android O developer preview is missing android.arch package

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I was using https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html in order to get started with the O developer preview, especially with the architecture package `android.arch`. I have the `android-O` folder in my SDK platforms folder (`~/Library/Android/sdk/platforms`) and set up my gradle file accordingly, but Android 3.0 cannot find the new classes , e.g. `ViewModel`. What's missing to make it work?

Related: [Android L Developer Preview packages missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643083/android-l-developer-preview-packages-missing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import Room Persistence Library to an Android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046877/how-to-import-room-persistence-library-to-an-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

@RobCo was right. Adding the following solved the issue:

```
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

See also: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html